# How to subtract elements of vector in r

Tags: r, entropy

I have a vector in R

```
myVect <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

Output i am looking for is

```
1-2-3-4 =-8
```

Is there a function that i can use for this

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `-`

```
Reduce(`-`, myVect)
#[1] -8
```

Or use `sum`

```
sum(c(myVect[1], -1*myVect[-1]))
#[1] -8
```